# Bash:ROSRUN:command not found

Tags: ros, bash, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need some help. I tried to modify some topics in other computer usin Node Manager but it sends me: bash: rosrun: command not found.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245356/bash:rosrun:command-not-found/) by [elputodelaesquina](https://answers.ros.org/users/28195/elputodelaesquina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most probably the environment on the remote is not properly sourced.

If this is not help, please provide a more in depth description of your actual problem.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0